# Why threading does not work in PyQt5?

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt5, qthread

Here is part of the code:

```
    ...
    self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.conc_thread)


def conc(self):
    self.textField.clear()
    word=self.searchBox.text()
    path=r'D:\\python1\wxPython\NYConc\Fiction'
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
        try:
            file=open(filename, 'r')
            read=file.read()
            file.close()
            pattern=re.findall(r'.{40} '+word+r' .{40}', read)
            for i in pattern:
                self.textField.append(i)
        except:
            continue

def conc_thread(self):
    tg=threading.Thread(target=self.conc)
    tg.start()
```

It gives me this error message:
"QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0xd08b98), parent's thread is QThread(0xc6f620), current thread is QThread(0x4a2c810)"

How can I solve that, please?

Comment: The message tells you what is wrong and what you shouldn't have done.

Comment: Could you help me solve that Ulrich? I'm new to both python and pyqt5. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Solve what? The facts are simple, you can't manipulate Qt-objects from the context of different threads than the one that owns them. Now, whatever you are trying to achieve must take this into account. I have no clue what you are trying to achieve though. If you just need a background worker thread, you must leave out the manipulation of Qt-objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your `self.textField` is a `QTextEdit`, whenever you call its `append` method, a `QTextCursor` is created as a child of the `QTextEdit` underlying `QTextDocument` object.
What's wrong with that?  Qt will not allow any QObject-derived class to have children 'living' in a thread different from the parent's one.
How to solve that? Since you're already using them, let's employ signals and slot.

First define a signal like this:

```
appendText = pyqtSignal(str)
```

and the corresponding slot:

```
def appendToTextField(self, text):
    self.textField.append(text)
```

connect them:

```
self.appendText.connect(self.appendToTextField)
```

then instead of:

```
for i in pattern:
    self.textField.append(i)
```

do:

```
for i in pattern:
    self.appendText.emit(i)
```

The `appendToTextField` slot is supposed to run in the right thread, the one where the `QTextEdit` underlying `QTextDocument` live, thus Qt will let new children be added to it.

Comment: Thank you so much, P-a-o-|-o. That solves the problem. But actually I need to use Thread to stop the GUI from freezing while running so that I can click the stopButton to stop the process. Signals and slot above do not solve that. I have self.stopButton but I can't click it because the GUI is freezing. What can I do next?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I added QApplication.processEvent() before emit(text).

Comment: @NuhYamin I'd you need to do that then chances are you are not actually doing the threading properly. Might be worth asking a new question about that so we can help get it right.